# Regular expression in the URL

Tags: regex

I want to exclude everything after `categoryId=` and the `ID`. note that the ID will change everytime.

> categoryId=46097316&fg=Color&ff=GenericColor&fv=Yellow&fd=Yellow&fg=Color&ff=GenericColor&fv=Ivory&fd=Ivory&fg=Color&ff=GenericColor&fv=Cream&fd=Cream&

I tried `categoryId=\d+`, but it will delete everything after `categoryId=`.

Comment: Your example regexp should work correclty, you want to keep only categoryId=46097316 right?

Comment: Yes i want to keep until the category Id = and the dymanic number

Comment: What do you mean until? there is no string before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want:

```
categoryId=[^&]+
```

This assumes you don't know the value type that can by in the categoryId (here it is assumed everything except a `&`)

Comment: so everything after category and its ID will get removed ?

Comment: @user5653362 does the above regexp help?

Answer (score 1):

`categoryId=(\d+)` should do the trick!

Comment: so everything after category and its ID will get removed ?

Comment: yep! Look here: https://regex101.com/r/dT5xN9/1 Assuming the ID is always numbers